# kendo mvc grid editor template with checkbox list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, checkboxlist, mvc-editor-templates

I have Kendo MVC Grid with Popup Editor template. 
I need to add Checkbox list for a model property. This is what I am doing

I declared a property in my view model like this...

```
public List<string> Category { get; set; }
```

This is how I am declaring Checkboxes in view

```html
<ul>
  @foreach (var g in (MultiSelectList)ViewData["BondPermitTypes"]) {
  <li class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Category" class="checkbox-removekvalid" id="Category_@g.Value" value="@g.Value.ToString()" />@g.Text
    </label>
  </li>
  }
</ul>
```

This code is working fine when I edit the existing records...

The problem is when I try to create new record and select any checkbox, all of the checkboxes are getting checked[image]

Moreover, even if I hack around using jquery and force it to check only selected checkboxes then when I post back the "Category" property has only one string all the time, which is "true".

I appreciate your help!

Comment: @saquib_adil: did you get this working? Please post your solution if you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply...

To make it work, I have added the default value for the Category property in the Kendo Grid. Like this

```
.Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.PkProperty);
            model.Field(p => p.Category).DefaultValue(new List<string>());
        })
```

Hope it helps you! :-)